# Design responding Triggers, defining and using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers

Recently I read about styles and control templates. As it says control templates are responsible for whole control design. But, I want for example to change only SPECIFIC part of the default control template, for example when mouse is over, or control has focus, when I wrote this:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleTextBox"  TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5, 0"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="#CCFBE6D9"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
</Style>
```

..whole template got overridden... and its kinda not cool...

So how to change only isMouseOver visual style, without overriding the whole default style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole template got replaced because your XAML says, "set the `Template` to *this* `ControlTemplate` that I'm declaring right here."  Problem is, your template is empty.  Use a template when you want to tell WPF, "represent the control using *this* visual tree".  You gave it an empty visual tree and got exactly what you asked for ;).

In this case, however, your intention isn't to change the visual structure of the control; you just want to change a property.  You can still use a `Trigger` and `Setter` for this, but you need not create a template to do so.  A `Style` has its own collection of triggers, so you can just move it there:

```
<Style x:Key="StyleTextBox"  TargetType="TextBox">
  <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5, 0"/>
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="SelectionBrush" Value="#CCFBE6D9"/>
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

This works because you're just changing a property of the styled control; generally, you can expect templates to honor the top-level properties of the controls to which the template is applied.  For example, the default TextBox template should ensure that the TextBox is drawn with a background conforming to the templated parent's `Background` property.

Triggers on templates are more useful in cases where you want to manipulate a specific sub-element declared within a custom template.